# Prove for any basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and invertible $m \times n$-matrix $A$ that $Av_1,\dots Av_n$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove for any basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and invertible $m \times n$-matrix that  $Av_1,\dots Av_n$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$. When tested with a random matrix, the statement was false so it is crucial that the matrix is invertible but I do not see how I can use the fact that the matrix is invertible in a proof.

Comment: if $m\ne n$ it's impossible for a matrix to be invertible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ is invertible if and only if the system given by
$$
x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \cdots + x_n v_n = b
$$
has a unique solution $x$ for every vector $b$.  This is the same thing as saying that a certain transformation is invertible.